# How to update all tables in a SQL Server database using a Loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a common column in all my tables in the database, and I need to update the value of this column through a loop in all my tables

I try by this code but nothing happened

```
DECLARE TBL_CURSOR CURSOR
FOR ( SELECT Name FROM Sysobjects WHERE Type='U' )

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQL = '';

DECLARE @TblName NVARCHAR(MAX);

OPEN TBL_CURSOR

FETCH NEXT FROM TBL_CURSOR INTO @TblName

BEGIN

   SET @SQL = ' If not exists (select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where  table_name = '+ @TblName +' and column_name = "CommonColumn") update ' + @TblName + ' set CommonColumn= 1 ';
  FETCH NEXT FROM TBL_CURSOR INTO @TblName
END

CLOSE TBL_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE TBL_CURSOR

EXEC (@SQL);
```

Anyone have a better idea or fixing up this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your code is the if statement....
You're updating the column, if it doesn't exist.

```
If not exists (select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA....
```

Also, you're overriding the value of @SQL every time, instead of appending to it.

```
SET @SQL = ' If not exists....
```

You don't need a loop to do this.
You can build up the update statement with one query, and then execute it.
Try this

```
DECLARE @SQL        NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQL = '';
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(o.name) + ' SET ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' = 1
'
FROM sysobjects o
    JOIN syscolumns c ON o.id = c.id
WHERE c.name = 'CommonColumn'
AND o.type = 'U'

EXEC (@SQL);
```

Comment: As of SQL Server 2005, I would recommend to use the **more focused** catalog views in the `sys` schema, like `sys.tables` and `sys.columns`, instead of the deprecated `sysobjects` and `syscolumns`